# Plpython UDF using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpython, sql-parser

I have a created a function that utilizes the sqlparse module to extract all of the tables hit from any given sql statement:

```
create or replace function my_function(x text) returns text
as $$
import sqlparse
from collections import namedtuple
from sqlparse.sql import IdentifierList, Identifier, Function
from sqlparse.tokens import Keyword, DML, Puncutation

*the rest of my parser program*

$$ language plpythonu;
```

When I execute the function this way:

```
select my_function('select foo from bar');
```

It returns: `bar`

When I execute the function this way:

```
select my_column, my_function(my_column) from schema.my_table;
```

It fails with:

> ERROR: XX000: ImportError: No module name sqlparse (plpython.c:5038)

Any feedback will be appreciated.